# cakePHP form submission results blank screen

Tags: cakephp, form-submit

I am facing a strange problem in cakePHP.
The issue is when ever i submitted a form it results a blank screen.
before submission the action work fine.
Do any body have any idea on this issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I voted this down because you found a solution and didn't provide any details and accepted a question that didn't solve the problem.

Comment: @david ryder : i found the solution and commented on the the answer which i accepted. so whether i need to add the solution as another answer and accept mu own answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things to help you check what is happening.

1- Check config/core.php and set DEBUG to 2. If you are getting a blank screen, this may not do anything.

2- Check your controllers / models. Make sure there is no blank lines after the ending ?> php tag. This could also cause blank screens.

3- Check syntax of your code. Try commenting out code to see if there is some code that may be improperly formed causing syntactical outages.

You can try posting your code so we can take a look. Maybe we can eyeball what is occurring.

Comment: @cdbugess : thankz for the quick response,  but the 3 things u list was not my problem. it was the problem with security component.
i forgot to add blackHoleCallback. hope this link may save time for some other fellow, http://www.sanisoft.com/blog/2010/08/09/adding-security-to-your-cakephp-application-part-2/

Comment: Maybe you could add the solution here so everyone knows what you mean. Is it just the standard (http://book.cakephp.org/view/267/blackHole-object-controller-string-error) or something else?